# MVVMCross bind property to a sub view android

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Fragment class which extends from MvxFragment.
This class takes a fragment view from Resources and inflates it in the main view.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ControlFragmentView, null);

            var chargeList = view.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.ControlChargeListView);
            chargeList.Divider = null;
            chargeList.Adapter = new MvxListElementAdapter(container.Context, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext, Mvx.GetSingleton<IThemeService>().ThemeViewControlChargeRecordListElement, typeof(ControlChargeRecordListElement));

            return view;
        }
```

This is my ControlFragmentView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MyApp.Droid.Controls.Control.ControlIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="ChargeValue ChargeValue;"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my ViewModel

```
public class ControlViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
     private float _chargeValue;
        public float ChargeValue
        {
            get { return _chargeValue; }
            set
            { 
                _chargeValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ChargeValue);
            }
        }
}
```

This is my MyApp.Droid.Controls.Control.ControlIndicator class

```
public class ControlIndicator : FrameLayout
{
    private float _chargeValue;
    public float ChargeValue
    {
        get { return _chargeValue; }
        set
        {
            _chargeValue = value;
        }
    }

    public ControlChargeIndicator(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : base(context)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private function Initialize()
    {
        var bar = new ControlBar(Context);
        AddView(bar);

        var bar2 = new ControlBar(Context);
        AddView(bar2);

        ....

        var barN = new ControlBar(Context);
        AddView(barN);
    }
}
```

And this is my ControlBar class

```
public class ControlBar : FrameLayout
{
    private float _chargeValue;
    public float ChargeValue
    {
        get { return _chargeValue; }
        set
        {
            _chargeValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make ControlBar subview aware that ChargeValue has been changed? I can detect when ChargeValue is changed in the ControlIndicator class but not in the ControlBar class. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wired up your `ChargeValue` property in your `ControlIndicator` class to the `ControlBar`'s `ChargeValue`. Why do you even have this kind of nesting?

Try changing:

```
private float _chargeValue;
public float ChargeValue
{
    get { return _chargeValue; }
    set
    {
        _chargeValue = value;
    }
}
```

To:

```
public float ChargeValue
{
    get { return _bar.ChargeValue; }
    set
    {
        _bar.ChargeValue = value;
    }
}
```

Make sure `_bar` is an instance of `ControlBar` as a member variable.

Comment: You are right. But how would you manage it if I had several ControlBar components? See my updated question above.

Comment: You expose a property for each of them.

Comment: I can't, because I don't know the exact number of ControlBar components that will be created.

Comment: Then you use some kind of List type of view to have them in.